# Why don't these two variables equal each other?

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to identify an object based on user input and have no idea why it's not working...

userInput is just a scanner, and allGames is an arraylist of a bunch of 'Game' classes with IDs like S01, S02 etc.

```
Game gameToChange = null;
for (Game g : allGames){
        System.out.println(g.getId());
}
String gameInput = userInput.nextLine();
    System.out.println(gameInput);
    for (Game g : allGames){
        if (gameInput == g.getId()){
            System.out.println("Found it");
            gameToChange =g;
        }
    }
```

The Game class:

```
public abstract class Game {

    private String identifier;

    public Game(String id){
        identifier = id;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return this.identifier;
    }
}
```

I have the printout for "found it" just so I can check when it's working...but no matter when I enter the correct string, one that matches one which is already printed out, it never equals it.

Comment: `String` comparison in Java is done using `String@equals` not `==`, the difference between comparing the contents of the `String` and the memory location of two different instances of `String`...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/3680684

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if (gameInput == g.getId()){
```

to

```
if (gameInput != null && gameInput.equals(g.getId())){
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh thanks, I get caught up in looking for bigger problems and forget about things like this. Appreciate it.

Comment: @JordanAndrews did you understand why?

Comment: I believe I was testing whether it was actually the same object, not whether the two strings were actually the same

Answer (score 1):

Since these two `gameInput` and  `g.getId()` are type Strings.

You should use `equals()` instead of `==`

`equals()` compare the content each variable

`==` compare the reference if they are looking at the same thing or not